# SElinux doesn't accept connection with private key

Tags: ssh, selinux

I have the following problem:

I installed SElinux, mapped my user as `unconfined_r` with sudo privileges and allowed SSH connections, but after I set up the enforcing mode can't log in anymore with `ssh` and private key.

When I try connect with `ssh` I get:

```
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
```

This is the configuration I did:

```
echo "myuser_user ALL=(ALL) TYPE=sysadm_t ROLE=system_r /bin/sh " > /etc/sudoers.d/myuser_user

getsebool -a | grep ssh

allow_ssh_keysign --> on
fenced_can_ssh --> off
sftpd_write_ssh_home --> off
ssh_sysadm_login --> on
ssh_use_gpg_agent --> off
```

Added the full SE Linux config I did, maybe can help for debug...

```
semanage user -a -r s0-s0:c0.c1023 -R "unconfined_r system_r" ubuntu_user_u

cp /etc/selinux/default/contexts/users/unconfined_u /etc/selinux/default/contexts/users/ubuntu_user_u

semanage login -a -s ubuntu_user_u -rs0:c0.c1023 ubuntu

echo "ubuntu ALL=(ALL) TYPE=system_sudo_t ROLE=system_r /bin/sh " > /etc/sudoers.d/ubuntu

chcon -R -v system_u:object_r:system_sudo_t:s0 /home/ubuntu/.ssh/
```

here the /var/log/audit.log that is generated when try log with ssh:

```
type=USER_AVC msg=audit(1606521919.331:151): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='avc:  denied  { start } for auid=n/a uid=0 gid=0 path="/run/systemd/transient/session-8.scope" cmdline="/lib/systemd/systemd-logind" scontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:systemd_unit_t:s0 tclass=service permissive=0  exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" sauid=0 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
type=USER_START msg=audit(1606521919.823:152): pid=1163 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=8 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='op=PAM:session_open acct="ubuntu" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=15.170.168.139 addr=15.170.168.139 terminal=ssh res=failed'
type=CRED_ACQ msg=audit(1606521919.823:153): pid=1231 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=8 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='op=PAM:setcred acct="ubuntu" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=15.170.168.139 addr=15.170.168.139 terminal=ssh res=success'
type=CRED_DISP msg=audit(1606521919.831:154): pid=1163 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=8 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='op=PAM:setcred acct="ubuntu" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=15.170.168.139 addr=15.170.168.139 terminal=ssh res=success'
```

audit2allow -w -a | grep "ssh"

```
type=USER_AVC msg=audit(1606522579.718:169): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='avc:  denied  { start } for auid=n/a uid=0 gid=0 path="/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service" cmdline="" scontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 tclass=service permissive=1  exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" sauid=0 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
type=USER_AVC msg=audit(1606522579.718:170): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='avc:  denied  { status } for auid=n/a uid=0 gid=0 path="/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service" cmdline="" scontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 tclass=service permissive=1  exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" sauid=0 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
type=USER_AVC msg=audit(1606522673.346:192): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='avc:  denied  { start } for auid=n/a uid=0 gid=0 path="/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service" cmdline="" scontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 tclass=service permissive=0  exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" sauid=0 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
type=USER_AVC msg=audit(1606522687.874:196): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='avc:  denied  { start } for auid=n/a uid=0 gid=0 path="/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service" cmdline="" scontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 tclass=service permissive=1  exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" sauid=0 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
type=USER_AVC msg=audit(1606522687.878:198): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='avc:  denied  { status } for auid=n/a uid=0 gid=0 path="/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service" cmdline="" scontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 tclass=service permissive=1  exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" sauid=0 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
type=AVC msg=audit(1606522853.067:220): avc:  denied  { relabelto } for  pid=1529 comm="chcon" name=".ssh" dev="nvme0n1p1" ino=256082 scontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:system_sudo_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=1
type=USER_AVC msg=audit(1606527581.704:277): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='avc:  denied  { status } for auid=n/a uid=0 gid=0 path="/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service" cmdline="" scontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 tclass=service permissive=1  exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" sauid=0 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
type=USER_AVC msg=audit(1606527582.256:278): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='avc:  denied  { start } for auid=n/a uid=0 gid=0 path="/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service" cmdline="" scontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 tclass=service permissive=1  exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" sauid=0 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
type=USER_AVC msg=audit(1606527704.324:293): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='avc:  denied  { start } for auid=n/a uid=0 gid=0 path="/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service" cmdline="" scontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 tclass=service permissive=0  exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" sauid=0 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
type=USER_AVC msg=audit(1606527713.724:297): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='avc:  denied  { start } for auid=n/a uid=0 gid=0 path="/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service" cmdline="" scontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 tclass=service permissive=1  exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" sauid=0 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
type=USER_AVC msg=audit(1606527713.724:298): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='avc:  denied  { status } for auid=n/a uid=0 gid=0 path="/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service" cmdline="" scontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 tclass=service permissive=1  exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" sauid=0 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
type=AVC msg=audit(1606567016.248:483): avc:  denied  { relabelfrom } for  pid=10828 comm="restorecon" name=".ssh" dev="nvme0n1p1" ino=256082 scontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:system_sudo_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
type=AVC msg=audit(1606567026.156:487): avc:  denied  { relabelfrom } for  pid=10830 comm="restorecon" name=".ssh" dev="nvme0n1p1" ino=256082 scontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:system_sudo_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=1
```

audit2allow -w -a | grep "auth"

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1606522853.063:219): avc:  denied  { associate } for  pid=1529 comm="chcon" name="authorized_keys" dev="nvme0n1p1" ino=256083 scontext=system_u:object_r:system_sudo_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:fs_t:s0 tclass=filesystem permissive=1
type=AVC msg=audit(1606522853.063:219): avc:  denied  { relabelto } for  pid=1529 comm="chcon" name="authorized_keys" dev="nvme0n1p1" ino=256083 scontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:system_sudo_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
type=AVC msg=audit(1606567016.248:484): avc:  denied  { relabelfrom } for  pid=10828 comm="restorecon" name="authorized_keys" dev="nvme0n1p1" ino=256083 scontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:system_sudo_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
type=AVC msg=audit(1606567026.156:488): avc:  denied  { relabelfrom } for  pid=10830 comm="restorecon" name="authorized_keys" dev="nvme0n1p1" ino=256083 scontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:system_sudo_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: Is there anything (relevant) in audit log `/var/log/audit/audit.log`?

Comment: sorry for the late answer. Added the audit.log.

Comment: I don't know SELinux enough to help, but a [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/136877/119298) shows how `audit2allow` (in the 2nd answer) might possibly provide some clues.

Comment: yes, I've already tryied it, but still didn't worked.

Comment: Is that on Ubuntu? (I've never used SELinux on any Debian-like distro.) What kind of a SELinux policy are you running there? The "targeted" one? It looks like something is royally messed up with your policy or file labels, given that `systemd` runs as `kernel_t`. Also, why is `.ssh` labeled `system_sudo_t`, when it doesn't have anything to do with `sudo`?

Comment: Have you relabeled the entire system after enabling SELinux? Have you tried running in permissive mode for a while to see if you get AVCs all over the place?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and running "default" policy (old targeted equivalent). Also tryied `semanage permissive -a ssh_keysign_t` and `semanage permissive -a sshd_t` and label `.ssh` as `sysadm_t` but still got  `client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe`

Comment: I'm actually running it in permissive mode, if I `setenforce 1` ssh with private key stop to work. How can I manage AVCs?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the first audit log message, split to multiple lines for better readability:

```
type=USER_AVC msg=audit(1606521919.331:151): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 \
subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 \
msg='avc:  denied  { start } for auid=n/a uid=0 gid=0 \
path="/run/systemd/transient/session-8.scope" \
cmdline="/lib/systemd/systemd-logind" \
scontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 \
tcontext=system_u:object_r:systemd_unit_t:s0 \
tclass=service permissive=0  \
exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" \
sauid=0 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
```

The type is `USER_AVC`, so this SELinux check was done specifically because user-space code requested it. So the user-space program that triggered it does explicitly support SELinux.

The `pid=1` indicates this check was done for the system's primary `init` process, which is apparently `systemd` in this case.

The `subj=` filed is `system_u:system_r:kernel_t`, so the `systemd` process in question was apparently started in the kernel's default SELinux context.

The `path=` and `cmdline=` fields indicate that `systemd` was apparently in the process of starting the user session scope, which would host the per-user `systemd` services for this user, and all the regular processes of this user.

Doing that would have required crossing the line between the source SELinux context (`scontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0`) and the target context (`tcontext=system_u:object_r:systemd_unit_t:s0`), to start the executable `/lib/systemd/systemd` in the target context. But according to the `msg=` field, it was denied.

This is a pretty fundamental operation in a system that is using `systemd`, so a well-made default policy would be extremely likely to cover it as a matter of course. **I would expect a production-grade system to not produce failures like this.** This makes me think your current SELinux policy might not be fully up to date for use with `systemd`.

Since your SELinux configuration includes `ubuntu_user_u`, this suggests you're using Ubuntu or some derivative of it.

Are you certain the SELinux policy you're using is up to date for the exact major release of the distribution you're using? If the system has been upgraded from one major release to another with e.g. `apt full-upgrade` or similar, there might be some extra steps you'll need to take to regenerate the active SELinux policy from the updated policy module files.

Comment: Yes, all the distro is updated, I did not upgraded from a previous release, It's ubuntu 18.04 server.